# How can i split a number value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I'm new on python and I'm trying to develop a program that gives informations about trains, from the JSON output I get (for example) "5506" and I would like to split it like "55" and "06".

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
json_trainNumber = 5506

a = 55
b = 06
```

Train numbers are always 4 digits so I'm trying to split this 2 digits by 2 digits.

Comment: Do you get the number as a string or int?

Comment: `b = 06` should rise SyntaxError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the output type is integer you could do use [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
json_trainNumber = 5506
a, b = divmod(json_trainNumber, 100)
print(a, b)  # 55 6
```

if you need strings:

```
strg = str(json_trainNumber)
a, b = strg[:2], strg[2:]
print(a, b)  # 55 06
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way:

```
json_trainNumber = 5506
a = json_trainNumber//100
b = json_trainNumber%100
print(a,b)
```

is to use division and remainder by 100.

Another method is to convert it to a string first, then extract the first two and the last two characters.

Comment: If the number is more than 4 digits in that case your code is not working.e.g Number = 550643 then your output is a= 5506 and b=43

Comment: we are told that it is always 4 digits. Otherwise, if the task is to extract first half and the second half, we can always compute the number to extract.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Convert to a string, then use slices to split and convert to int again

```
json_trainNumber = 5506

temp_str = str(json_trainNumber)

a = int(temp_str[:2])
b = int(temp_str[2:])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to split it as you did in your question, you could first convert it to a string and use index slicing.

```
train_str = str(json_trainNumber)

a = int(train_str[:2])
b = int(train_str[2:])
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Convert number to string and split using below code:

```
Number = str(5506)
l = int(len(Number)/2)
a,b = Number[:l],Number[l:]

print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
55
05
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str` function in the assignment

```
json_trainNumber = 5506
a = str(json_trainNumber)[:2]
b = str(json_trainNumber)[2:]
print(a,b)
```

or

```
json_trainNumber = 5506
a, b = str(json_trainNumber)[:2], str(json_trainNumber)[2:]
print(a,b)
```